# Liquibase: Maven Plugin ignores logicalFilePath when relativeToChangelogFile is set to false

Tags: maven, spring-boot, liquibase

i've created the following changelog file:

```
<databaseChangeLog
        xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog
         http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.1.xsd"
        logicalFilePath="path-ignored"
>
  <include file="db/changelog/usermanagement/db.changelog-master.xml"/>
  <include file="initial/db.changelog-initial.xml" relativeToChangelogFile="true"/>

</databaseChangeLog>
```

All my files have the logicalFilePath attribute. When I update my database using the maven plugin, all change sets that are included via the first file (db/changelog/usermanagement/db.changelog-master.xml) have a relative path in the filename column of the databasechangelog table.
All change sets included by the second file (initial/db.changelog-initial.xml) have "path-ignored" as filename.

When I drop everything and let the server doing the update (I'm using spring boot), the filename of all change sets is set to the logicalFilePath value (path ignored). This is what I expected.

I'm using liquibase 3.5.3.

The databasechangelog scripts are located in different projects. That is the reason why I don't set the relativeToChangelogFile to true for the first included file.
Of course, I can move all scripts into the same project, but this is not what I want.